# Plugin to send messages to members/lists but not full-blown newsletters

Tags: plugins, email, lists

I'm looking for a plugin that would allow the owner of a school to send student members short email messages. We don't need a full-blown newsletter feature but it does need to be able to have multiple lists (kids classes, adult classes, etc). Users don't need to talk to each other, just get a message that, for instance,  the 10am class is cancelled, etc. Something like mailchimp seems like overkill and too much work for the client.  Ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google turned up this post - [How to Email Subscribers from WordPress](http://digitalrenewal.com/email-subscribers-from-wordpress)

Which recommended ...

> [Email Users](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-users/) is probably the simplest email plugin, and seems to do the job. It picked up my existing subscribers from the database and sent an email. It does exactly what it’s supposed to do.